# Is it possible to have animated launcher icons for android apps?

Tags: android, icons, android-icons

I am just curios if Android supports animated launcher icons like the iOS has the Calendar app which always shows the current day or the Clock which has a moving hand on the icon.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps [Android Stack Exchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! But allow me to disagree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not in general. Android has [app widgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) for that.

Some home screen implementations might offer developers an API to have animated launcher icons, but that would be up to those specific home screen implementations. There is nothing standard in Android for this.

Comment: Well that's a bummer... Thanks for the quick answer though!

Comment: Check out the clock icon on the galaxy. It updates even the seconds needle. So it is possible now.

Comment: @thunderboltz: You are welcome to offer proof that this is not a feature of the home screen of whatever device you are using. As I mentioned in the answer, home screen implementations are welcome to do whatever they want.

Comment: @CommonsWare whats about Clean Master android app (also animate icon 1 Tap Boost)

Comment: @Rana: No app animates its home screen launcher icon, except on home screens that offer an API for it (if there are any).

Comment: it wasn't possible before android Oreo https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive.html

Comment: Oreo's adaptive icons don't support general animations. But there is now a way to implement clock hands, at least on some launchers: https://www.xda-developers.com/clock-icon-android-o-custom-launchers/