# How to have animated icon like Apple clock for NativeScript

Tags: android, ios, nativescript

Is it possible to have animated icon like Apple has for it's clock for ios 11 and above using nativescript? I found answer for ios [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361654/how-to-animate-application-icon-in-ios) and that says The iOS SDK does not allow you to change/animate your apps icon. Apple's own apps are ofcourse an exception.

But that answer is from 2013 and I am wondering if this is still the same case.

And for android I think we can have App widgets as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463068/is-it-possible-to-have-animated-launcher-icons-for-android-apps) answer.

P.S. I have tagged 'NativeScript' as I am using that for my apps development.

Comment: The case is still the same for Apple. Animated app icon for iOS is still unavailable for third-party developers.

Comment: @paulw11 I have referenced that question in my post and linked as well. That is for ios7 while I have asked for ios12.

Comment: The answer is still valid.  Nothing has changed.  I dare say that for iOS it will never change.  Allowing an app to execute continually in the background in order to update an icon is incompatible with the iOS execution model.

Comment: Fair Enough, I'll delele the post not to confuse others.